# Javascript Regex Split Words that ends with dot, exclamation, question mark, comma and on whitespace

Tags: javascript, regex, split

I need to split a string on words that ends with a dot, exclamation/question mark, comma and space.

For example:

`var s = "An example, string, That have weird? formatting!"`

When on `s.split()` will result in:

`["An", "example", ",", "string", ",", "That", "have", "weird", "?", "formatting", "?"]`

Comment: What is the end result? do you actually want the `,` and `?`

Comment: Yes, i need the delimiters(?!,.) included in the array form .split()

Comment: better off with match and not split

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should probably use match() with grouping to get what you want and not use split. The basic idea is match a word or match the special characters.

```js
var str = "An example, string, That have weird? formatting!"
var result = str.match(/(\w+|[,?!])/g)
console.log(result)
```